# MVC - Display the previously selected value in dropdown as top/first item if we open again

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement as follows,

If we reopen dropdown list again after selected a value in the first time, the dropdown should show the selected value as the topitem and show the remaining items

In simple terms, User opens a drop down list, select a value, closes it.
Again reopen the dropdown, here the selected value should come top.

Example:
Following is the dropdown where user select will select value 3

[image: dropdown values]

And when he reopens it, the value 3 should come top

[image: last selected value first]

Last time we have implemented it using combobox in windows forms. Now we are trying it in MVC

Is it possible to implement it in MVC?

Comment: what do you mean by ** reopen dropdown list**. There is a option called selectedIndex you can use javascript, jquery on any other framework which you are using.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Mvc DroupList Pass Value

In Search For Index Page

```
  public ActionResult Index(string ComCurncy)
  {
    ViewBag.CurnceyID = new SelectList(db.TBLCurrnceys, "CRID", "CUName", 
    ComCurncy);
  }
```

In Create Or Edit

```
public ActionResult Create(TBLBillAlert tBLBillAlert)
{
   ViewBag.BillCurnceyID = new SelectList(db.TBLCurrnceys, "CRID", "CUName", 
     tBLBillAlert.BillCurnceyID);
 }
```

pass Select Value

```
  public ActionResult Index(string ComCurncy)
  {
    ViewBag.CurnceyID = new SelectList(db.TBLCurrnceys, "CRID", "CUName", 
    "3");
  }
```

in View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("BillCurnceyID", ViewBag.BillCurnceyID as SelectList, "- Curncey-", new { @id = "BillCurnceyID", @name = "BillCurnceyID", @class = "form-control" })
```